# fitting a statistical distribution using scipy

Tags: scipy, distribution, data-fitting

I am trying to use Scipy to fit a theoretical distribution to my empirical data using code similar to:

```
dist_names = ['gamma', 'beta', 'rayleigh', 'norm', 'pareto']
for dist_name in dist_names:
dist = getattr(scipy.stats, dist_name)
param = dist.fit(data)
pdf_fitted = dist.pdf(x, *param[:-2], loc=param[-2], scale=param[1]) #* size
```

The fit() function uses a data series of observations. My problem is that I already have the empirical distribution in form of an x-array with the bin values (0,1,2.,3....,n) and a corresponding y-array with the probability for each bin. Can anyone advise me how to use my x/y arrays in the fitting process rather than the original series?

Comment: Although a histogram provides a nice visual representation/summary of the data statistics, it contains *less* information than the actual (raw) data. Therefore, a fit based only on histogram information is expected to be less accurate. If you have the data available, use them to perform the fitting with scipy. Otherwise, you need to devise your own custom fitting function based on histogram information since I don't think scipy can do this. There might be some other library available that can do that; I am not aware of one.

Comment: @Stelios *I don't think scipy can do this.* Fitting a PDF to the histogram is just a [curve fitting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) task, which scipy can do with relative ease. However, I totally agree with *don't fit on the histogram unless the raw data is irretrievably lost*.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. In my case the x-axis observations is integer and the y-axis is integer count already so I don't think any information is lost. However rather than expanding my data into a series I will look for other means to do the task.